# Handling landscape display on iphone device rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on an iphone app with tab bars each one associated to a navigation controller. In one of these controllers I've a Table View showing some listing and when a row is selected another view displays specific informations and a button to see some related photos.

I'm having an issue displaying the photo view in landscape.

The photo view controller contains a UIImageView to display one photo at a time and this ImageView object size is 320x460 showing in full screen mode. To handle rotation I've added the following code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

But it's not rotating and iphone simulator status bar is still in the portrait position, so not rotated too.

I've also changed the method like this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return YES;
}
```

Still no changes on device rotation. And the options in **Project->Summary(Tab)->Supported Device Orientation->Desired Orientations** clearly enable landscape mode (right/left).

Can you help me understand what I may be missing ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a tab bar controller, it will only rotate if your view controllers for *all* your tabs allow the orientation. Kind of annoying, but there it is. You need to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in all your other view controllers too, and they need to be able to smoothly adjust to those orientations.

If it's not practical to support landscape orientations on the other view controllers, maybe you could try some hacking, for example by subclassing UITabBarController and overriding its shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to instead return YES if the *current* view controller returns YES. But that might get your app rejected as not conforming to Human Interface Guidelines, since you are trying to circumvent standard interface behavior.

Comment: do you think I can calling the view modally could fix this ?

Comment: just override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in the view controllers that are opened by the tab control and use the code above :)

Comment: @StephaneKouakou I don't know what happens with rotation with a modal view controller pushed from a tab bar controller.

Comment: but how should I prevent rotation on views I don't want while enabling it on a specific view ?

Comment: As I said, override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation on a subclass of UITabBarController (which takes the place of your standard UITabBarController). That might work, but I think you will have to tweak it a little to get it to work just right. You are going to have some work ahead of you either way. Either figure out how to make some tabs rotate but others not, which is discouraged behavior, or figure out how to display _all_ your tabs in both orientations, which might be more work but actually adds value for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're not in some sort of a subclassed container view controller (like your own UINavigationController or UITabBarController subclasses). If that's the case make sure it does not override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method.

Answer (score -1):

Your looking in the wrong place: in your RootViewController.m file look for the following code:

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
//lots of useless comments
//
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation) ); //THIS LINE HERE
// return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandScape(interfaceOrientation) );
```

the line that says return (UIInterface... Portrait) is the line that determines your app's rotating capabilities. You can change this to whatever to allow you to be able to rotate completely, keep it at a certain orientation, or whatever you desire...